# Rendering info from the Reddit API using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, reddit

I am trying to build a basic web app where a user can search for subreddits using the Reddit API.
However, while I can `console.log` the data I need from the API I cannot seem to figure out how to display it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Amplify, { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify";
import aws_exports from "./aws-exports";
import { withAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut }  from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";
import './App.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import CharacterGrid from './components/CharacterGrid'
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar'

Amplify.configure(awsconfig); 

const App = () => {
 
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true)
      const result = await axios(
        `https://www.reddit.com/subreddits/search.json?q=${query}`
      )

      setItems(result.data)
      setIsLoading(false)
    }

   fetchItems()
  }, [query])

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <AmplifySignOut/>
      <SearchBar style={{ marginTop: "6%" }}  getQuery={(q) => setQuery(q)} />
      <CharacterGrid isLoading={isLoading} items={items} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default withAuthenticator(App)
```

The child component `CharacterGrid` looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import CharacterItem from './CharacterItem'

const CharacterGrid = ({items, isLoading}) => {

  return 
    isLoading 
      ? (<h1>Loading ...</h1>) 
      : (
        <section className='cards'>
          <p>{items.data}</p> //this does not work
          <p>{items.children}</p> //this does not work either
        </section>
      )
}

export default CharacterGrid
```

All I want to do is show the names of the subreddits that are returned from the API for the query string the user enters. Where am I going wrong? I have also tried converting to JSON, and mapping through the responses using .map() but I keep getting errors no matter what I try. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: " Where am i going wrong?" is what you should say. What is the problem here, what error do you get where do you get?

Answer (score 1):

> However, while I can console.log the data I need from the API I cannot seem to figure out how to display it.

Because Reddit API returns an array of subreddits you should use `map()` function to [iterate over the array and convert each item into React element](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components).

```
items.map(i => (
  <li key={i.data.display_name_prefixed}>
    {i.data.display_name}
  </li>
))
```

> All I want to do is show the names of the subreddits that are returned from the API for the query string the user enters.

You need to inspect the data schema yourself and **scrape** the response properly.

---

Here is working example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    if (query.length >= 3) {
      axios(`https://www.reddit.com/subreddits/search.json?q=${query}`)
        .then(response => setItems(response.data.data.children))
        .catch(error => console.log("Error", error));
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [query]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={query} onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
      <CharacterGrid items={items} isLoading={isLoading} />
    </div>
  );
}

const CharacterGrid = ({ items, isLoading }) => {
  return isLoading ? (
    <h1>Loading ...</h1>
  ) : (
    <ul>
      {items.map(i => (
        <li key={i.data.display_name_prefixed}>
          {i.data.display_name} ({i.data.display_name_prefixed})
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I had thought that this was the issue and tried to fix it myself but kept getting cannot "map items of undefined" or something to that affect. Thank you for your help, I was incredibly frustrated, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop through the elements and e.g: print the title, you could do the following.

```
items.data.children.map(child => <p> child.data.title </p>)
```

According to the response provided by reddit,
[reddit response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE1j2.png)